# Installing Several Individual Wordpress Sites in Nested subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nested, subdirectory

I have a wordpress installation in my root, here is the .htaccess for it:

I have a directory called /websites in which developers have FTP access to work on client wordpress installations

In this directory could be any number of other wordpress installs such as /company1  /company2  etc.

So the urls for these nested installs would be /wwwroot/websites/company1/ and so forth.

The issue is that while wordpress will let me install into any first level subdirectory from the root, the second nesting breaks the .htaccess.

How can I setup my .htaccess so that when a drop a new site into /wwwroot/websites/base/ it will work as intended?

EDIT: I have tried this suggestion from vico but still get a 404 error in /wwwroot/websites/base/  Here are the exact copies of the files:

**/wwwroot/.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**/wwwroot/websites/.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**/wwwroot/websites/base/.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /base/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /base/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry previous answer was intended for something else.

To install wordpresses in the 2nd Level just remove all first level files and htaccess files

## /wwwroot/content/

`-/subdir1/`

`----wordpress file and htaccess here`

`-/subdir2/`

`----wordpress file and htaccess here`

`-/subdir3/`

`----wordpress file and htaccess here`

I think wordpress will take-care of everything if you just move a fresh copy into each directories and run the wordpress setup on each

Comment: That doesn't work for me, that's what I started with and hoped would work, but no joy.  IE: Default wordpress .htaccess in webroot, nothing in the second level dir and then default .htaccess in the third level subdirectories... no joy, I get a 404 on any index.php in those directories (but not other files)

Comment: No wordpress htaccess codes on anything but the wordpress installed sub directories

Comment: Doing this method gives me a 404 themed in the wordpress installation from the web root.  I have tried this with no .htaccess in root, or in subfolders, no .htaccess in root, but default in subfolders as well.

Comment: there might be some kind of syntax error in your htaccess.. There shouldn't be any reason why a 404 would show up. have done the same setup before. why dont you try a new empty hosted environment (if possible and start fresh and just create some sub directories and unzip some wordpress into those sub directories) and run wp-install on all.